# Error after applying patch to authorize.net module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, authorize.net

I have applied patch from MD5 to SHA-512 to Magento 2 Authorize.net direct post module, when i tried to test purchasing with a credit card i got this error on exception.log file

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit : in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Response.php on line 111
```

this is the code line 111

```
return strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $message, pack('H*', $signatureKey)));
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Have you checked patch applied successfully. Please also check manually if the changes from patch file have changed. Since less number of changes are made manual checking would be easier. The patch works successfully and there is no problem with the patch

Comment: when i tried patch -p1 < patch_name it displays which file to patch i don't know it's a normal way?
yes i checked the files, they are changed